# Submit a command "sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm" for ever

Tags: sudo, kvm-virtualization

My **AVD** in android studio has a problem when i want to run it then i searched and i used this command  `sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm` and it works.

My problem is when i start my **PC** , i should type this for using **emulator** , it has a way for **submitted** it for ever.

My OS : "Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS"

Comment: You set access to something for everyone with `chmod 777` OK? then i want to use this just once for ever , not per time that i start my linux ubuntu, the access will remove when i restart my OS. @Nmath

Comment: "Submit a command “sudo chmod 777 -R /dev/kvm” for ever" is the wrong question. Your  question is "how can a user use /dev/kvm".

Comment: @Rinzwind , User can use it as i wrote a command in question , i want to user use it for every time that log in to ubuntu.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is never going to work: `/dev/` is rebuild every boot. Besides that chmod 777 is never the correct solution. The only time chmod 777 is a solution is when it is for a tmp situation where you also use the sticky bit.

The way to do this: please check the GROUP of `/dev/kvm` (with `ls -l /dev/kvm`) and add the user you want to use that device to that group.

The group is likely to be `kvm` so what you need to do is

```
sudo adduser $USER kvm
```

Adjust it to the group `/dev/kvm` shows though. You need to logout before it is activated too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , i checked that after i reboot my system and if it was true i accept it.

Comment: I faced with this :  `The group  kvm  does not exist.`

Comment: Please edit your answer because i think that if `sudo adduser $USER kvm` does not work we should use `sudo chown $USER kvm`

Comment: No, chown is still wrong and Rinzwind's answer is right IMHO - I assume you use a non-ubuntu qemu then as the package `qemu-system-common` would have created the group for you. `qemu-kvm.service` fixes the permissions on each boot (in bionic, later on systemd/udevd/logind will do)).

Comment: @ChristianEhrhardt , Yes exactly when i try to `sudo apt install qemu-kvm` i faced with this `The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gsettings-desktop-schemas : Breaks: mutter (< 3.31.4) but 3.28.4-0ubuntu18.04.2 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
` error.